# Bernoulli Polynomials from Apostol's calculus book

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, polynomials

Question 35 from book of calculus, volume 1 Apostol, in chapter "The relation between integration and differentiation".

Define Bernoulli polynomials as: $P_0(x)=1$, $P'_n(x)=nP_{n-1}(x)$, $\int_0^1P_n(x)dx=0$ if $n\geq1$

Prove:

f) $P_n(1-x)=(-1)^nP_n(x)$ if $n\geq1$

g) $P_{2n+1}(0)=0$ and $P_{2n-1}(\frac{1}{2} )= 0$ if $n\geq1$

Facts that may help (previous letters that I already solved):

c)$P_n(0)=P_n(1)$ if $n\geq2$

d)$P_n(1+x)- P_n(x)= nx^{n-1}$ if $n\geq1$

e)$\sum_{r=1}^{k-1} r^n= \int_0^kP_n(x)dx=0= \frac{P_{n+1}(k)-P_{n+1}(0)}{n+1}$ if $n\geq2$

Comment: E.g. https://www.mathi.uni-heidelberg.de/~theiders/PS-Analysis/Bernoullische_Polynome.pdf and endless many literature by internet search.

Comment: thx ^^. Although I don't know german, I used google translate and I understood his solution.

Comment: Sorry, haven't thought about the language.